# Apscheduler cron trigger not running

Tags: python, cron, apscheduler

I'm trying to use ApScheduler to run a task at the beginning of every minute. When I run the code below, I get no output. Any ideas?

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

def hello():
    print('hello')

scheduler.add_job(hello, 'cron', minute=1)
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: How long did you wait? It runs after 1 minute for the first time.

Comment: I waited about 3 minutes and got no output. Do you get 'hello' when the minute changes on your clock, or exactly 1 minute after you started the program. I had something working a while ago, but that was acting like the 'interval' mode, where it runs the hello function exactly 1 minute after the program is started.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!
Turns out that the way to get the functionality I wanted was to use `minute='*'`. Using `minute=1` will run the hello function at the first minute in every hour, not on every minute change.

Comment: Ah yes, I looked at the code too hastily myself and mistook it for an interval trigger.